# Browser returns "No data received" for my Amazon EC2 instance over and over again

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, rds

I've experienced two times now of the "No data received" issue ever since I've moved my WordPress site to use RDS.

Though I could still connect to my RDS via MySQLWorkbench, but not able to connect to my instance via SSH (It shows "Operation timed out") after this issue has happened each time.

Doing "ping" in Terminal would show that my instance is "100.0% packet loss", and rebooting the instance would not fix this issue neither. I've set the correct IP for the SSH in the security groups inbound rules, and also checked that my instance is appear to be running on the EC2 console. The browser would still returns "No data received.".

Interestingly, I've found that stopping the instance, and then restart the instance and the httpd service would fix the issue. However, this issue will always come back again after couple of hours.

Could anybody help me or guide me to troubleshoot it, please?

Comment: Have you got an elastic IP on the instance?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have found the reason viewing my instance's log. It didn't have enough memory for httpd. I had to change to a t2.large instance type to keep my wordpress site running, which costs me more... will get away from Amazon EC2 now.. Thanks for replying!